# Pardot Certification - Account creation

Tags: pardot

I wanted to look into Pardot for Salesforce. But I am stuck in the very initial step of creating Pardot account. My questions  -

1. Can I create a free Pardot account. If yes where? I already tried - https://pi.pardot.com/user/login but can not login using SF.
2. I already installed the Pardot package, but can we do not sure how I can log into Pardot.

Please give me some pointer to start with..Thanks

Ray

Answer (score 3):

I actually asked a Pardot rep this question at the Salesforce World Tour in Chicago a few weeks ago. At this time, you are not able to register for a free developer account or anything similar to what Salesforce offers for developers - however, you can request a personalized demo from [here](http://www2.pardot.com/sem/ww/0614/demo-request), but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. I wanted to study for Pardot certification. Is there any way for same if I can not even create a Pardot org :(

Answer (score 3):

Unlike with Salesforce, you cannot just create a trail Pardot org. You should try to contact the Pardot support team to see if this is even possible, but I doubt you will get it without any purchasing decision in the near future.

On your second point, I guess you mean you installed the Pardot app in your Salesforce org. This is actually just a connector which links your Salesforce org to your Pardot org (which you don't have atm). Currently, those 2 use a complete different database.

Comment: Thanks for details.Yup i installed Pardot connector then..Does SF have any way to create dummy Pardot org? else how is anyone supposed to study or test anything on it.?

Comment: There is no way to create a Pardot org without going through Pardot support. They can provide you a training environment (we have one at our company), but I think they generally only give that when you already have a production org as well. But it doesn't harm to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The Pardot Administrator should create you as a user and if you try to login from salesforce.com it will ask you to relate to the pardot account for the first time. If you are the pardot administrator should be able to login.